# $C^1[a,b]$ functions at endpoints

Tags: derivatives

I have a question regarding the definition of continuously differentiable functions defined on a closed interval, i.e. $C^1[a,b]$. For $f$ to be in $C^1[a,b]$, do we require the one-sided derivatives to exist at the end points and that $f'$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, or only that $f'$ exists and is continuous on $(a,b)$? Thanks.

Comment: Is it clear that if the one-sided derivatives exist, then $f'$ will be one-sided continuous at the endpoints?

Comment: It is the former.

Comment: one sided derivative exists at the endpoints.